# UI-Router ionic Card List

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have some problem with using href in ionic div. If I use ionic list all work good:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" href="#/app/posts/{{post.id}}" track>
```

But when I try this on div - don't work:

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" href="#/app/posts/{{post.id}}" track></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ng-href` instead? Also, not sure how exactly you expect `href` attribute to be of any meaning on `div` element. It's not the same for `ion-item` directive - if supplied with `href` attribute, its content is rendered in `<a>` element ([details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29937692/1229023))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href` is not available inside `div`. You can workaround using `ng-click` and handling it in the controller.

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" ng-click="gotoPost(post.id)" track></div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.gotoPost(postId){
    $location.path('/app/posts/'+postId);
}
```

Keep in mind that you will ned to inject `$location` in you controller

Comment: @KingStakh Can you please set the answer to accepted? :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. This:

```
    $scope.gotoPost(postId){
    $location.path('/app/posts/'+postId);
}
```

Change to this:

```
      $scope.gotoPost = function(postid){
      $state.go('app.post', {'postId': + postid});
  }
```

And add $state to my controller

Answer (score 0):

Declaring function just for routing in every place could be cumbersome. Use this approach instead.

```
<div class="list">
  <a class="card item" 
     ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" 
     ui-sref="post({id: 'post.id'})" >
    <div>{{post.content}}</div>
  </a>
</div>
```